# KeyError: 'Unable to open object (wrong B-tree signature)'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

When I was running the project which is based on Mask R-CNN, I am stuck with this problem. 
The configuration is cuda=9.0 cudnn=7.1.4 tensorflow-gpu=1.9.0 and keras-gpu=2.2.4
However, when this program is running in Windows10. It has encountered with above problem which is described more closely as this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-5-e5959b6300f2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Mask R-CNN/test.py', wdir='D:/Mask R-CNN')

   File "D:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3-5.3.0\envs\cv2\lib\site- 
    packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

   File "D:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3-5.3.0\envs\cv2\lib\site- 
    packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

   File "D:/Mask R-CNN/test.py", line 49, in <module>
    model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True, exclude=[ 
   "mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc"])

   File "D:\Mask R-CNN\mrcnn\model.py", line 2131, in load_weights
    saving.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f, layers)

   File "D:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3-5.3.0\envs\cv2\lib\site- 
    packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 1104, in 
    load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name
    g = f[name]

   File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

   File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

   File "D:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3-5.3.0\envs\cv2\lib\site- 
    packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)

   File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

   File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

   File "h5py\h5o.pyx", line 190, in h5py.h5o.open

   KeyError: 'Unable to open object (wrong B-tree signature)'
```

Could anybody help me? 
SOS!

Answer (score 0):

In `model.load_weights` you use h5py to load weights from save file. This library has problems reading the file. There are at least two possible explanations:

1. The file is corrupted. Try to download it again or use programs to view hdf5-Files to check. That worked for me, when I ran into this error.
2. The version of h5py you have installed is not compatible with the version with which the file is written. See [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1155).